# Simplify PowerShell runbook to send e-mail

Tags: azure, powershell, certificate, azure-keyvault, runbook

Can I simplify my PowerShell Azure runbook to gather soon to expire secrets and certs (vs repeating code) from all KV's in subscription and send a formatted table in an e-mail?

The current runbook runs fine with the associated modules configured to the automation account in the subscription but I'm positive there is a much cleaner way to run this and have a formatted email go out to stakeholders periodically.

```
Param(
        [string]$SubscriptionID = "",
        [int]$DaysNearExpiration = "30",
        [string]$VaultName
)
 
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionID | Select-AzureRmSubscription | Format-Table -Autosize
 
$ExpiredSecrets = @()
$NearExpirationSecrets = @()

#gather all key vaults from subscription
if ($VaultName) {
    $KeyVaults = Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $VaultName
}
else {
    $KeyVaults = Get-AzureRmKeyVault
}
#check date which will notify about expiration
$ExpirationDate = (Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays($DaysNearExpiration) -Format yyyyMMdd)
$CurrentDate = (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd)
 
# iterate across all key vaults in subscription
foreach ($KeyVault in $KeyVaults) {
    # gather all secrets in each key vault
    $SecretsArray = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVault.VaultName
    foreach ($secret in $SecretsArray) {
        # check if expiration date is set
        if ($secret.Expires) {
            $secretExpiration = Get-date $secret.Expires -Format yyyyMMdd
            # check if expiration date set on secret is before notify expiration date
            if ($ExpirationDate -gt $secretExpiration) {
                # check if secret did not expire yet but will expire soon
                if ($CurrentDate -lt $secretExpiration) {
                    $NearExpirationSecrets += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                        Name           = $secret.Name;
                        Category       = 'SecretNearExpiration';
                        KeyVaultName   = $KeyVault.VaultName;
                        ExpirationDate = $secret.Expires;
                    }
                }
                # secret is already expired
                else {
                    $ExpiredSecrets += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                        Name           = $secret.Name;
                        Category       = 'SecretNearExpiration';
                        KeyVaultName   = $KeyVault.VaultName;
                        ExpirationDate = $secret.Expires;
                    }
                }
 
            }
        }
    }
         
}
 
Write-Output "Total number of expired secrets: $($ExpiredSecrets.Count)"
$ExpiredSecrets
  
Write-Output "Total number of secrets near expiration: $($NearExpirationSecrets.Count)"
$NearExpirationSecrets

$ExpiredCertificates = @()
$NearExpirationCertificates = @()

#gather all key vaults from subscription
if ($VaultName) {
    $KeyVaults = Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $VaultName
}
else {
    $KeyVaults = Get-AzureRmKeyVault
}
#check date which will notify about expiration
$ExpirationDate = (Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays($DaysNearExpiration) -Format yyyyMMdd)
$CurrentDate = (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd)
 
# iterate across all key vaults in subscription
foreach ($KeyVault in $KeyVaults) {
    # gather all certificates in each key vault
    $CertificatesArray = Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $KeyVault.VaultName
    foreach ($Certificate in $CertificatesArray) {
        # check if expiration date is set
        if ($certificate.Expires) {
            $certificateExpiration = Get-date $certificate.Expires -Format yyyyMMdd
            # check if expiration date set on certificate is before notify expiration date
            if ($ExpirationDate -gt $certificateExpiration) {
                # check if secret did not expire yet but will expire soon
                if ($CurrentDate -lt $certificateExpiration) {
                    $NearExpirationCertificates += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                        Name           = $certificate.Name;
                        Category       = 'CertificateNearExpiration';
                        KeyVaultName   = $KeyVault.VaultName;
                        ExpirationDate = $certificate.Expires;
                    }
                }
                # secret is already expired
                else {
                    $ExpiredCertificates += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                        Name           = $certificate.Name;
                        Category       = 'CertificateNearExpiration';
                        KeyVaultName   = $KeyVault.VaultName;
                        ExpirationDate = $certificate.Expires;
                    }
                }
 
            }
        }
    }
         
}
 
Write-Output "Total number of expired certificates: $($ExpiredCertificates.Count)"
$ExpiredCertificates
  
Write-Output "Total number of certificates near expiration: $($NearExpirationCertificates.Count)"
$NearExpirationCertificates
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible refactoring (untested):

```
Param(
        [string]$SubscriptionID = "",
        [int]$DaysNearExpiration = "30",
        [string]$VaultName
)
 
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionID | Select-AzureRmSubscription | Format-Table -Autosize

$ExpiredSecrets = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]] @()
$NearExpirationSecrets = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]] @()

#gather all key vaults from subscription
$KeyVaultArgs = if( $VaultName ) { @{ VaultName = $VaultName } } else { @{} } 
# In PS 7+ you could write:
# $KeyVaultArgs = $VaultName ? @{ VaultName = $VaultName } : @{} 
$KeyVaults = Get-AzureRmKeyVault @KeyVaultArgs

#check date which will notify about expiration
$ExpirationDate = (Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays($DaysNearExpiration) -Format yyyyMMdd)
$CurrentDate = (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd)
 
# iterate across all key vaults in subscription
foreach ($KeyVault in $KeyVaults) {
    # gather all secrets in each key vault
    $SecretsArray = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVault.VaultName | Where-Object Expires

    foreach ($secret in $SecretsArray) {
        # check if expiration date is set
        $secretExpiration = Get-date $secret.Expires -Format yyyyMMdd
        # check if expiration date set on secret is before notify expiration date
        if ($ExpirationDate -gt $secretExpiration) {
            $secret = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name           = $secret.Name
                Category       = 'SecretNearExpiration'
                KeyVaultName   = $KeyVault.VaultName
                ExpirationDate = $secret.Expires
            }

            # check if secret did not expire yet but will expire soon
            if ($CurrentDate -lt $secretExpiration) {
                $NearExpirationSecrets.Add( $secret )
            }
            # secret is already expired
            else {
                $ExpiredSecrets.Add( $secret )
            }
        }
    }       
}

# omitted unmodified code ...
```

Changes:

- Use `[System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]]` instead of plain array. This is much more efficient when the array can grow large. Powershell recreates a plain array to size +1 whenever operator `+=` is used. A `list`'s internal array will be resized only in multiples of two instead.
- `$KeyVaultArgs = if ...` uses conditional assignment to create the parameters as a hashtable and then uses [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1) to need only a single call to `Get-AzureRmKeyVault`.
- `$SecretsArray = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVault.VaultName | Where-Object Expires` lets us get rid of the `if ($secret.Expires)` within the `foreach`, reducing nesting level.
- `$secret = [PSCustomObject]@{` to remove duplicate code from the `if/else` construct below. Also slightly cleaner syntax than `New-Object PSObject`.
- `$NearExpirationSecrets.Add( $secret )` and `$ExpiredSecrets.Add( $secret )` are required because `list` doesn't support the `+=` operator.

Comment: Thanks @zett42....your refactored code works as expected! Do you happen to know how I pull in certificate info (or better if I could pull everything soon to expire) from the KV as well with your script? My script basically repeated the same logic twice, upper requesting secrets and the lower requesting certs.

Comment: @Grant Somehow I missed the lower part ;-). Let me see if I find some time later this day...

Comment: No worries @zett42. Thanks!